# Is there any one time API key / access token to access Salesforce API

Tags: salesforce

I'm getting Bearer token for Salesforce API by providing `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username` and `password` as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm).

For some reasons, I don't want to provide username and password each time to get access_token.

Is there anything within Salesforce to get one time API Key or `access_token` to access Salesforce API endpoints?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  OAuth 2.0 JSON Web Token (JWT) bearer for getting the access token . You can take reference from this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5